# Passive Sony/Minolta a/af mount Stabilization

Tags: lens-mount, image-stabilization, minolta

I shoot from a Minolta Maxxum 7000 AF. I know it definitely won't support any active image stabilization solution. AFAIK there's some passive solutions that are lens-only, but I don't know of any for the A/AF mount.

Are there any passively stabilized a mount lenses I could use with my camera?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by active and passive stabilisation?

The A-mount is used on older Minolta Maxxum/Dynax/Alpha SLR/DSLR cameras, and on newer Sony Alpha DSLR/DSLT cameras. Stabilisation, if available, for this system has always been implemented as *in-body* stabilisation – where the sensor moves. It was introduced with the Maxxum 7D DSLR in 2004, and was marketed as 'Anti-Shake'. Sony calls it 'SteadyShot Inside'. There are no A-mount lenses with any *in-lens* stabilisation technology.

Sony also has the E-mount, with some E-mount lenses having in-lens stabilisation, but that's a different kettle of fish. E-mount lenses are not compatible with the A-mount, even with an adapter, so you can disregard them for your scenario entirely.

For the Maxxum 7000, your best option is to stick with faster shutter speeds (I like to follow the *reciprocal-of-focal-length* rule), use a tripod, remote release and faster film. Also consider if flash can help to remove the need for longer shutter speeds in low light.

Comment: There are also some handheld stabilisation systems *external to the camera* available and widespread these days - eg steadycams, gimbals and gyros, but these are optimized for video and while handheld, still large and heavy.

Comment: Passive stabilization is a design that is based strictly on inertia and gravity, with no active motors or servos to move lens elements. Instead, it is left up to Newtonian physics, usually using some type of counterweight system, or even a gyro used to stabilize a platform, on a sort of multi-axis gimbal type attachment between optical elements and the lens barrel or camera housing. I'm not sure I've ever seen such for the consumer 135 format market, though. "Prehistoric" LF reconnaissance cameras are where I've seen it.